# Where are the Win 10 Quick Access settings stored?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Where are the Windows 10 Quick Access settings stored?

I have a large number of Win 10 computers and I want to deploy a "Pinned Folder" into user's Quick Access section of Windows Explorer using group policy.

Comment: Related question: [Unable to add files/folders to Quick Access on Windows 10: “Unspecified Error”](http://superuser.com/questions/969012/unable-to-add-files-folders-to-quick-access-on-windows-10-unspecified-error)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The Quick Access items are stored in this file:

```
%appdata%\microsoft\windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms
```

Comment: And the Microsoft Team blog covers how to deploy the setting.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/supportingwindows/archive/2015/12/21/users-can-39-t-access-the-desktop-and-other-resources-through-quick-access-in-windows-10.aspx

Comment: Perfect answer, good research. Only problem is they dump all the links into one file, so I can't manipulate it via group policy except for putting in a default one for new users.

Comment: Thanks Dom. And it's prone to corruption from what I see in various forums. When a pinned item gets stuck, the file needs to be cleared and that resets the entire listing. http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-quick-access-reset-pinned-shortcuts-stuck-not-working-windows-10/

Comment: related: [How to know “.automaticDestinations-ms” files to which app relates?](http://superuser.com/q/217646/120159) and maybe [Decrypt/Read/Modify “.automaticDestinations-ms” and/or “.customDestinations-ms”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4429944/1266650)

Comment: Looks like the file depends on OS's language...

Comment: It looks like these have been moved somewhere in version `1809`

Comment: @MasterofCelebration, that's not a comment on this answer. It's discussed elsewhere: https://superuser.com/q/947292

Comment: For others having trouble finding it, it's in the roaming folder, the `Recent Items` folder is the same as `Recent`, the AutomaticDestinations folder won't show up in Explorer even if hidden files/folders are displayed, and the file itself is not simple text so manually editing it isn't easy.

Comment: Is there a way to edit this quick access config file? I have a problematic link that connects to a remote location through FTP and it doesn't let me right click it to unpin it from Quick Access.

Comment: @w32sh Microsoft Team blog link is dead: "404 - Page not found"

Comment: as for the dead Microsoft link, wayback machine ftw! https://web.archive.org/web/20160117015258/http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2015/12/21/users-can-39-t-access-the-desktop-and-other-resources-through-quick-access-in-windows-10.aspx

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with group policy - here is how I do it:
Create shortcuts to the shares in %USERPROFILE%\Links:
[GP preferences - shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq2aO.png)

Set the shortcut details:
[GPPref details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euGd8.png)

Then again use GP Prefs files to delete the jumplist file %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1oaL.png)

The jumplist file will recreate a moment later with the contents of the links folder