# Windows 10 File Explorer: "Working on it ..."

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Does anybody know how to get rid of the annoying "**Working on it ...**" Message in the **Windows 10 File Explorer**.

It stays there (on the right side) for a few seconds to many seconds when opening the file explorer.

OS Window 10
System Partition SSD
All other files which are used often are also on a SSD
(only one HDD for bigger files which are also not used often, exists)

So showing recent files should really be fast.
Also I do not mind if there is an option to deactivate this feature.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Is this happening for any folder or only Quick access view in particular?

Comment: go in the settings app and stop real time protection of Windows defender. is it faster now?

Comment: @w32sh This is happening when using the short-cut "Windows Key" and "E" to open the Windows File Explorer. It takes especially long after a reboot. But sometimes also a few seconds if the Explorer was used already.

Comment: @magicandre1981 thx for the hint, I do not what to do that. But I'm gonna test if this is cause and will let you know.

Comment: Open Folder Options > Set "Open File Explorer" to "This PC"
Try WinKey + E now. If it opens fine, then problem is with Quick access caches.

Comment: @w32sh This sounds good. I'll try later when at home. Can you place you last comment as an answer so I can accept if it works?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Open Folder Options > Set "Open File Explorer" to "This PC". Try WinKey + E now. If it opens fine, then the problem is with [Quick access cache](https://superuser.com/questions/1051440/where-are-the-win-10-quick-access-settings-stored), which can be cleared by deleting the file `f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms` from the following directory, using Command Prompt.

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations
```

**Note:** The above procedure clears your Quick access links. You'll have to manually add the links again.

Comment: Works like a charm :)

Comment: My PC still had the problem after setting the folder options to "This PC", but deleting the cache files still solved the problem! Thank you!!

Comment: The 'This PC' step allows me to access file explorer.  And I can access the links under Quick Access successfully, but I cannot click on Quick Access without crashing the File Explorer.

Comment: +1 delete the cache files - also fixed slow opening of This PC' for me.

Comment: My downloads folder was doing this exclusively. Drove me nutters. Deleted, it instantly recreated a couple of files, and wham! My downloads folder instantly refreshed showing my files. Thank you so much!

Comment: I had a lot of Quick Access folders in my Explorer, after deleting those files they are all gone. Please update your answer to include the fact that all your links will be gone after this step!

Comment: @gonutz : Thanks. I've added a note below the answer.

Comment: This worked well as a solution, but only for the first day or two. Then it all went back to where it was previously: "working on it...".

Comment: Worked great, love the level of knowledge required to answer this, a true windows spelunker from days past I bet.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, a couple of folder locations on remote file systems had found their way into the quick-access cache. These remote systems had become inaccessible, so my Windows Explorer was waiting for them to time out before rendering.

Deleting them from the Quick Access panel did the trick for me.

Another thing you can do, especially if you have lots of filetypes Microsoft recognizes in your download folder (stuff like jpg, docx, xlsx, etc):

Right click on your Downloads folder and choose Properties.
Click the Customize tab.
Choose Optimize this Folder for .... General Items.
Click "also apply this setting to subfolders."
Click OK.

Repeat for your Documents folder.

This will let the Windows Explorer handle your files without trying to generate snapshot images for your files.

Comment: Worked for me, windows 10 pro 2019

Answer (score 8):

Short version, the Windows Search service  and the Windows Index are having issues.

Launch Control Panel and launch Indexing Options.

Click the Advanced button and you should see an error saying that there is no index.

Click the button to Rebuild the Index and give it 10 seconds and you’re done !!!!

Comment: Rebuilding the index fixed it for me.

Comment: Fixed it for me. My `WSearch` service refused to start, but after setting it to `DelayedAutoStart`, running error checking on my system drive, and restarting, things are back to normal. My icon cache was also broken, which might be a related symptom.

Answer (score 8):

The only thing I found to work was opening a folder (not from the one in the taskbar, but one on the desktop or other means). Below are those steps for Windows 10 Pro:

1. Open a folder
2. On toolbar go to View -> Options (far right) -> Change Folder and Search Options
3. Under Privacy click Clear next to Clear File Explorer History
   [image: Screenshot]
4. Click OK and close the folder. Now open the folder from the taskbar.

THIS RESOLVES THE ISSUE SINCE A FILE THAT IS STORED FOR QUICKACCESS MAY NOT BE ACCESSIBLE.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work when Explorer is *"Working on it..."*, because the **Options** button on the **View** tab is disabled.

Comment: I tried manually clearing the AutomaticDestinations folder and setting the Quick Access to This PC.  Pressing the Clear button on Folder Options is what finally fixed it for me.  Thanks!

Comment: it works but after i restart the computer it happens again... any permanent solution to this?

Comment: You can access this dialog only when you have a working explorer. So if your explorer already doesn't start normally, you have to trick it into opening some other folder on your disk, then immediately go the this dialog.

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution for this problem on another site. Just right click on the folder with the problem and go to properties. There switch to Customize tab and set the option "Optimize folder for:" to General items. Worked like a charm :)

Comment: Worked for me. My case was a secondary non-OS D: drive that was full of video files. It was optimized for "Videos" and I changed it to "General Items" and that fixed it. Sidenote: I tried the above changes and those did not work so this might be the best case for non-primary drives. Thanks Kadju!

Comment: Yes! This made my downloads folder MUCH faster to open. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found that if, after I tried to open windows explorer the first time and it hung, I could right click the explorer and open a second windows explorer (while the first one was still hung) it opened fine. I then closed the hung one and used the second. This is only a temporary fix. Right now I'm doing the Re-Indexing under Indexing Options to see if this fixes it.

Ok... the re-indexing fixed it (at least for now)

Comment: Opening the second window works for me, but re-indexing does not.... so +1 for at least getting a working explorer .... wish I could -1 Windows, though ;-)  Other solutions on this page have not helped me at all (yet).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues. It turned out to be onedrive causing the problem. I fixed by right clicking onedrive icon in tray, and then clicking "unlink this PC". Once that was done, everything worked again, including thumbnails and folder options, and the 'working on it' hang up was gone as well

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue.  It only affected one user.  I had previously changed my wife's 'Pictures,Music,Documents' etc folders locations to a drive that was no longer connected.  Once I remapped them to a location that was valid it cleared up instantly.

Comment: Are you saying this is the only problem that can cause the symptoms described, or is this just something to try? If it's just something to try, it isn't an answer ans should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

the answer of Win32Guy worked for me, but the location was slightly different:

```
%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent Items\CustomDestinations
```

i deleted all the files in this folder and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Even after following the suggestions in the other answers my explorer kept being slow. My specific issue was the recently used files - because many of them were on network drives.

I've simply disabled the **recent files**-part.

1. Right click `Quick Access`
2. Click `Options`
3. Remove the marking in `Show recently used files in Quick access`
4. Click `OK`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was deleting all of the files from the problematic folder (`Downloads`). Since I had Git Bash installed, I was able to run:

```
cd ~/Downloads
rm -rf *
```

If you don't have Git Bash, you can do:

1. Press Windows-R
2. Enter `cmd`
3. Enter `cd Downloads`. Make sure this is successful before going to the next step.
4. Enter `dir` to see the files in the current directory. Don't go on to the next step until you are sure you are in the right place and don't mind losing these files.
5. Enter `rd /s /q .` This [removes all the files and subdirectories in the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14491010/631051).

The last command should give the error: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.` That just means it didn't delete the directory you were in.

Of course, if your problem is in a different directory, `cd` there. In any case, make absolutely sure you are in the correct directory before running `rm` or `rd`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ellen, but I don't think most people want to delete all their files as a solution to the problem.

Answer (score -1):

After a recent install of 10 on my P.C., the File Explorer view tab had sections that were greyed out, and I couldn’t preview any photos. The thumbnails and icon just would never come up. So, I searched and searched and attempted all of the solutions found…..but nothing. Until one day I started the Task Manager and saw a reset button on the lower right side of the window. I highlighted file explorer, hit the reset button and like magic, my thumbnails, icons and view settings appeared. This is the only fix I found. If it doesn’t work on the first try, just do it again; it usually doesn’t take more than three attempts.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide [good answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to questions people ask. Part of writing a good answer is making sure people can easily find the core of it. Please reformat your answer so that it is clear what *exactly* the solution is. Please also add some more detail on where you found the button, because it doesn't seem to be available without opening some menu.

Answer (score -1):

What I did was

1. hold down the Left shift key, right-click on the File Explorer Icon, and select Properties.
   [image: Image for step 1]
2. Select the Shortcut Tab at the top
3. Change the contents of the Run drop-down from "Normal Window" to "Maximized"
   [image: Image for step 3]

This worked for me, I hope it helps others

Comment: Does this really remove the "Working on it..." message? This only tells explorer to open in a maximized window, doesn't it?