# Windows 10 Icons not showing, explorer loads slow, processes are fine

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, icons, teamviewer

Last night I connected to my office computer with team viewer and I had some problems on loading Explorer (Quick Access Folder) took forever to load, I thought something related my internet connection but next day desktop icons were missing, (white file icon) folders took forever to load.

[image: missing icons]

Tried every answer on this topic [Windows 10 File Explorer: "Working on it ..."](https://superuser.com/questions/1083525/windows-10-file-explorer-working-on-it)

Now Explorer loading fine, but still desktop and some app icons are missing. (Removing recently used files for quick access did trick)

Additionally, I've tried;

- updating icon cache through registry
- Rebuilding search index
- removing IconCache.db

While I'm writing after taking this screenshot all icons now are white file icon except folders and Recycle Bin
What could it be?

Update: I've added another user, icons are visible on that one. Now 'm thinking user profile is corrupted. somehow.

Comment: quicker to create a new user, login as that user, then copy your stuff over from the broken profile ....

Comment: Whole chunks messing is worrying. I suggest some malware checks ([helpful post](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)),as well as disk checks.

Comment: @harrymc that would be weird, because I consider myself a power user and, since this is my office computer there is no cracked software at all, only recent change is chrome update. Which is only software with a visible icon, and I just added secondary user, that one works quite normal.

Comment: That might solve the immediate problem, but the main question is "what happened". This can be a disk problem, an anti-virus that went berserk (happened to me), or whatever. You might find a hint in the Event Viewer. I wouldn't ignore such a problem.

Comment: @harrymc I was just pointing out a fact. I didn't ignore it and still using the same account for further investigation. Checking out Event Viewer is might be a good idea. Thanks

Comment: Update: Disk Cleanup seems like fixed problem.
I checked: Temporary Files, Thumbnails, Delivery Optimization Files, DirectX Shader Cache, Temporary Internet Files, Downloaded Program Files then suddenly icons appeared all at once.

Comment: If that's the case, then your system disk is almost full. Take steps to free up more space, since this condition can make the computer unbootable.

Comment: Hmm, 45gigabyte space is available. Additionally, start menu search is still not working.