# Windows 10 File Explorer - Where are Quick Access shortcuts stored?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I searched for a means to import my old Windows 7 Windows Explorer `Favorites` into the new File Explorer `Quick Access` of Windows 10.

I read many posts about the differences between them regarding their functions (pinning of folders in Quick Access) but after all that, I wonder if there is a location where these shortcuts are stored (such as C:\User\AppData...).

I work on a network and have saved many shortcuts in the Windows 7 favorites. I've had to change my computer which now runs with Windows 10.

Comment: It's covered here: https://superuser.com/questions/1051440/where-are-the-win-10-quick-access-settings-stored

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, they were stored here: %USERPROFILE%\Links

Comment: They *are* stored there.

Comment: No not on my Windows 10 unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be stored under %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\