# Opening zip file slows down explorer if SVN enabled folder is in quick access list

Tags: windows-10, zip, tortoise-svn, windows-10-quick-access

I have a couple of SVN folders in my quick access list, and TortoiseSVN installed. After opening a .zip file using Explorer's built-in viewer, Explorer slows down whenever a file is selected. This problem persists even after navigating away from that .zip to some other place, until a new Explorer window is opened.

This problem also occurs even if you don't open the .zip file, but instead select the file and open the "Compressed Folder Tools" on the ribbon.

It seems like it's trying to repopulate the "Extract to" list everytime a file is selected. I've tried resetting the quick access list using the method in [Where are the Win 10 Quick Access settings stored?](https://superuser.com/questions/1051440/where-are-the-win-10-quick-access-settings-stored) and confirmed that the slow down no longer occur, until it's populated with SVN folders again.

Meanwhile, I could associate the .zip files with some other zip viewer (7-zip) and avoid the problem altogether, but if possible I'd like to keep the default viewer, for reasons.

Is there a way to avoid the slow down?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, except when using QTTabBar 1038 on Windows 10 build 1607. Uninstalling QTTabBar fixed the issue and file explorer no longer lagged when dealing with zip files. Although the offending program is different in both of our cases, they are both essentially Windows File Explorer shell plugins in some capacity, so it seems to be related. Did you ever solve this issue? If so, how?

Comment: Upon closer inspection, without QTTabBar installed, File Explorer does start to lag ever so slightly after opening up a zip file, but it is nowhere near as noticeable as when it is installed. Apparently there's something about these shell extensions that exacerbates the issue (which I assume is on Microsoft's side).