# Can I remove the "Desktop" shortcut from Quick Access in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I can remove just about everything from the Quick Access section of Explorer in Windows 10, but not the shortcut to the Desktop(red arrow in image):

[image: (see red arrow in attached image)].

When I right-click the link, I have an option to **Unpin from Quick Access** (just like every other link in this area). But when I click it, nothing happens, and the shortcut remains.

Why won't it go away, and how can I force it to behave?

Version details: Windows 10 Version 1803 Build 17134.765

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why won't it go away, and how can I force it to behave?

You should be able to remove the entry.  You can clear all Quick Access items by removing the following file.  The file will be recreated once you add an entry to the Quick Access list.

```
%appdata%\microsoft\windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms
```

Source: [Where are the Win 10 Quick Access settings stored?](https://superuser.com/questions/1051440/where-are-the-win-10-quick-access-settings-stored)

Comment: Thanks, Ramhound! This worked. When I deleted that file, Quick Access reset to containing Desktop, Downloads, Documents, and Pictures - but now it let me delete all of them.

Regarding the version of Windows I'm on, it's out of my hands (corporate IT rolls out what they like, when they like). But I appreciate this advice in general :)